# tab tamer - problems with hiding tabs

Tags: 7, users

I have found quite nice drupal module, the "[tab tamer](https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer)". It allows admin to edit labels of tabs and sub tabs, but also disable or enable them. I have install the module, and set that user/register and user/password to "Disabled". Unfortunately I can see all the time both labels. Did I make something wrong? I use the latest drupal7. Great thank for any tips or advices :)

nykon

Comment: Is there any reasons why you are opting to go with a module instead of using CSS? I have used tab tammer many times, but still think yours is a small requirement and you can go with CSS and save some rework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal uses the *not-logged-in* CSS class which is used for the `<body>` tag. The following CSS style will hide the registration and login form tabs. It is the easiest way to achieve the task.

```css
.not-logged-in .tab-class{
  display: none
}
```

Comment: Yes thats what I meant. But we are not sure why he is so specific to go with module instead of css.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make this with CSS, instead of going with Tab tammer module. If the module has no other specific work to do than hiding the tabs, i would insist you to opt CSS. This can reduce the rework of configuration and save memory space by evading from a module.